# How to customize serialization behavior without annotations in Salat?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, salat

I'm using Salat library to serialize objects to be stored in MongoDb via Casbah. Sometimes I need to tune little bit how fields will be serialized, and Salat's Annotations is a pretty convenient way to do it.

BUT, Is there any way to describe serialization parameters(Key, Ignore etc) not directly in case-classes(models) via Annotations, but in some external point, to keep my models clear from Salat dependency(aka POJO/POCO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom serialization logic to your Salat context.

Example from Salat unit tests:

[WibbleTransformer](https://github.com/salat/salat/blob/c2b8dee550c59a4f586f6a4e692d00bd38bdaf7e/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/custom/model.scala)

[Custom context with custom transformers added](https://github.com/salat/salat/blob/c2b8dee550c59a4f586f6a4e692d00bd38bdaf7e/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/custom/package.scala)

Comment: Thanks, this is not to say a super-convenient way to tune serialization, but, probably, the only one we can use in "external point". Anyway, it works.