# salat serialize Map[Enum,Boolean] type

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, salat

Hi I would like to serialize/deserealise to DBObject some map with enumeration as key using salat.

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val VAL_ONE, VAL_TWO = Value
}
case class CanBeStored(a:Enumeration.Value)

case class CanNotBeStored(a:Map[Enumeration.Value,Boolean])
// Produces exception[[ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map]]
```

As I understood it is not possible using current version.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-salat/s3Q548NM8yc

But may be there exists some round way to do it ? The real problem is that I have a rather deep nested case class model wich describes my Mongo datamodel and i can not just change serialisation to custom implementation.

May be I can build some custom Transformer direct for Map[MyEnum.Value,Boolean] but how ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement custom transformers that could convert the String keys stored in mongo to your enum objects.

See: [How to customize serialization behavior without annotations in Salat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545841/how-to-customize-serialization-behavior-without-annotations-in-salat)

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to implement my own salat like library but on macros: https://github.com/martende/mondao